# Has Holocaust Remembrance Day been used to commemorate what happened to indigenous peoples?

Tags: world-war-ii, judaism, genocide

Some individuals have described what has been done by some countries to some indigenous peoples as genocide. For example, [Australia Day parties without the white guilt: The failed sentiment of the Hottest 100 poll](https://www.sbs.com.au/nitv/article/2017/08/07/australia-day-parties-without-white-guilt-failed-sentiment-hottest-100-poll)

> The way nations’ remember is no accident - even more so for a
>   settler-colonial society like Australia. It serves the settler in this
>   country to deny that it’s foundations are genocide and dispossession.
>   It serves the settler to deny that it is the beneficiary of such
>   genocide and dispossession. It serves the settler to believe it is the
>   self-made country. Our existence as Aboriginal and Torres Strait
>   Islander people is, as John Howard referred to, a “blemish” in the
>   history they tell themselves.

Has [Holocaust Remembrance Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Holocaust_Remembrance_Day) been used to commemorate genocides other than the Nazi Holocaust? If so, has that included genocides against indigenous peoples? Either by governments, or non-government organisations that are reasonably mainstream, and are not maliciously trying to dilute out the Jewish link to the event.

Comment: To add a little context. Holocaust Memorial day is on 27th January, the day when Auschwitz was liberated. Australia day is on the 26th January, the day when the first fleet arrived in Australia. .... In your question do you mean "has Holocaust rememberace day been used *by any government or national body* to remember indigenous people"?

Answer (score 5):

The proper noun "*Holocaust*" in that day's title seems to confine the answer within the boundaries of that instance of genocide.

But other genocide remembrance days, which vary both in scope and adoption, include:

- [Genocide Memorial Day](http://www.ihrc.org.uk/activities/projects/9928-introduction-to-gmd)
- [International Day of Commemoration and Dignity of the Victims 
  of the Crime of Genocide and of the Prevention of this Crime](http://www.un.org/en/events/genocidepreventionday/)
- [Black Ribbon Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Day_of_Remembrance_for_Victims_of_Stalinism_and_Nazism)

More specific days include:

- [Armenian Genocide Remembrance Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_Genocide_Remembrance_Day)
- [International Day of Reflection on the Genocide in Rwanda](http://www.un.org/en/preventgenocide/rwanda/commemoration/annualcommemoration.shtml)

Among the UN's many [international days](http://www.un.org/en/sections/observances/international-days/) are a selection of remembrance, commemoration, and solidarity days that overlap both with each other and the above days somewhat, so that victims of genocide might also be remembered on more than one of those days, such as:

- International Day of Solidarity with Detained and Missing Staff Members
- International Day for the Right to the Truth concerning Gross Human Rights Violations and for the Dignity of Victims
- International Day for the Elimination of Sexual Violence in Conflict
- United Nations International Day in Support of Victims of Torture

Apparently the world's nations are a bit self-conflicted about genocide, there being more national histories which either seem to have included genocide, (or have aided and abetted it), than there are nations that have been willing to openly acknowledge it.  It's unclear if the systemic causes of such nationalist reticence are due to nations being oblivious, absent minded, hoodwinked, brainwashed, amnesiac, vain and devious, or something else.
But when the mote is in a neighboring nation's eye, that's often enough  acknowledged, and the above international inconsistency of remembrances seems to be the overall outcome.

Comment: although "holocaust" is a word which originally (and arguably currently) refers to any instance of massive (human) destruction